# Model property value inconsistent

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have a view model, that contains an array of classes. The model contains a boolean value called "isJobber". The array in that model sets some more boolean values based on the "isJobber" value (plus some more booleans) to determine if some specific fields can be edited by the user.

I was seeing some inconsistencies with the editable/non-editable fields so I added a "debug" property to each item in my array inside the model.

The debug property has:

```
debug = isJobber.ToString();
```

And my model has the property "isJobber". The model is returning true, while the debug property is returning false.

I'm using Knockout with this to be able to see all of these values in chrome debugging tools.

How the heck is this possible. The isJobber value NEVER gets changed from the time it's used to populate the array to the time it gets populated in the parent model. Here's all of the code, in full:

```
var isJobber = _storeRepo.Query().FirstOrDefault(s => s.OwnerID == ownerId).Jobber;
var goalViewModel = goals.Select(g => new GoalViewModel {
    GoalId = g.GoalId,
    MonthName = GetMonth(g.Month),
    Month = g.Month,
    LYMonthSales = g.LYMonthSalesAdjusted,
    LYMonthSalesActual = g.LYMonthSalesActual,
    CYMonthGoal = g.CYMonthGoal,
    CYMonth = g.CYMonthAdjusted,
    CYMonthActual = g.CYMonthActual,
    ExpoDollars = g.ExpoDollars,
    LYSalesEditable = isJobber && (currentDate.Year < 2014 || (activeMonth == null && currentDate.Month <= g.Month) || activeMonth <= g.Month),
    CYSalesEditable = isJobber && currentDate.Year >= 2014 && activeMonth != null && activeMonth == g.Month,
    GoalEditable = (lastProcessedMonth == null || lastProcessedMonth < g.Month),
    Debug = "currentDate: " + currentDate.ToShortDateString() + "; isJobber: " + isJobber + "; activeMonth: " + activeMonth + "; Month: " + g.Month + "; lastProcessedMonth: " + lastProcessedMonth
}).ToList();

return View(new EarnbackModel {
    EnrollmentId = enrollment.EnrollmentId,
    CustomerName = enrollment.Customer.CustomerName,
    TotalPackagePrice = packages.Where(p => p.CancellationDate == null).Sum(p => p.Price),
    EarnbackCap = enrollment.EarnbackCap ?? 0,
    EarnbackCapMax = isJobber ? 1000000m : 5000m,
    DefaultGoalPercent = 7,
    Ars = arSelections.ToList(),
    Goals = goalViewModel,
    IsJobber = isJobber,
    AvailableStores = stores,
    LastProcessedMonth = lastMonth,
});
```

Here's the output from chrome developer tools:

```
viewModel.IsJobber()
true
viewModel.Goals()[0].Debug()
"currentDate: 12/22/2013; isJobber: False; activeMonth: ; Month: 1; lastProcessedMonth: "
```

One thing I noticed via Chrome Developer tools, our server hosting this site thinks it's 12/22/2013...don't think it has any effect on my property value, but worth noting...

**In response to PW Cad's comment/question:** Here's the cshtml code for the knockout stuff. Does this answer the question about the isJobber being observable? Since it's in the view model, doesn't that make it observable()? By the way, I'll start working on the jsFiddle, thought I've never done it before.

Also, this works just fine in my development (localhost) and test websites. Only production does not work...

```
    var raw = @Html.Json(Model);
    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(raw);
```

Here's the jsFiddle, but I don't know how to make it worthwhile without some actual data...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsx38/)

Here are my models:

```
public class EarnbackModel
    {
        public EarnbackModel()
        {
            Ars = new List<ArSelectionViewModel>();
            Goals = new List<GoalViewModel>();
            AvailableStores = new List<StoreViewModel>();
        }

        public int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalPackagePrice { get; set; }
        public decimal EarnbackCap { get; set; }

        public decimal EarnbackCapMax { get; set; }

        public decimal DefaultGoalPercent { get; set; }

        public IList<ArSelectionViewModel> Ars { get; set; }
        public IList<GoalViewModel> Goals { get; set; }

        public bool IsJobber { get; set; }

        public IList<StoreViewModel> AvailableStores { get; set; }

        public NewARViewModel NewAr { get; set; }

        public int LastProcessedMonth { get; set; }
    }

public class GoalViewModel
    {
        public bool MonthClosed { get; set; }

        public int GoalId { get; set; }
        public string MonthName { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public decimal LYMonthSales { get; set; }
        public decimal LYMonthSalesActual { get; set; }
        public decimal CYMonthGoal { get; set; }
        public decimal? CYMonth { get; set; }
        public decimal? CYMonthActual { get; set; }
        public decimal? ExpoDollars { get; set; }

        public bool LYSalesEditable { get; set; }
        public bool CYSalesEditable { get; set; }
        public bool GoalEditable { get; set; }

        public string Debug { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Is your isJobber property an observable or not?  It looks like you are using it interchangably.  Something else doesn't make sense - if you toString a boolean it should be 'false' not 'False', could you create a jsFiddle to reproduce the error you are having?

Comment: Are you just using Knockout for debugging purposes? If so, I'd recommend using Glimpse instead as Knockout introduces an entirely new layer with it's own potential for bugs. Glimpse will allow you to see the properties returned from your view model. If you're only testing the initial state of the model, this is the way to go. If you are having trouble with the state of the model being returned from your MVC controller, can you please post your C# model as well?

Comment: No, there are numerous fields on the page that are populated (from the GoalViewModel) where the user can edit and see other values change on the fly, which is why Knockout is being used.

Comment: @PWKad I edited my question to [try] and answer your question/comment

Comment: Look at your page source where the model is being converted to JSON, can you verify whether the resulting JSON contains the initial value you'd intended.

Comment: @VinneyKelly I'm getting the same thing from the page source...Debug = isJobber = False

Comment: Which you'd expected to be True right? If so, I think there might be an issue with the way MVC is serializing your model which is why I had asked you to post your c# model. Is there anything funny about your isJobber property on the c# model? Is the object returned by the controller initialized correctly?

Comment: @VinneyKelly I don't think so. (I'll add the model after this). The viewModel is returning the way I expected (the incorrect way) where the IsJobber property on the model is true, but on the GoalViewModel is being interpreted as false. It tells me that the problem is on the C# side, prior to any serialization that occurs...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43773/discussion-between-vinney-kelly-and-ganders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works in development but not in production then it would appear that either something is being changed by a Release configuration or there's something wrong with the production environment or the deployment package. Perhaps try packaging and redeploying. If that doesn't work try deploying to another server.